# set variable to field name of sql query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, dynamic

My goal here is to set a variable to a field name from a mysql query. Some pseudo code below

```
1.    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE userName = 'mhopkins321';"
2.    $result = mysql_query($result);
3.    $while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
4.         $column1 = name_of_column($row['firstName']);
5.    }
6.    echo $column1

      //Would return the string

      firstName
```

obviously line 4 being the real pseudo part

Comment: maybe i'm wrong... but wouldn't column1 be "firstName"? why dynamically grab it when you statically type it into the array. Do you just want to get all of the column names of the table? (since you're using mysql... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)

Comment: yes, its somewhat difficult for me to explain. I either need to be able to have two variables, one for the value of the row, and one for the field name; or a single variable that is an array with those two. `$firstName = ['firstName','michael'];

Comment: either that, or I need to set the name of a variable as a string in a different variable

Comment: it looks like that may have been depricated, however `SHOW COLUMNS` is a sql function. I can attempt to play around with that to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
$query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE userName = 'mhopkins321';"
$result = mysql_query($result);

$all_results = array();
$while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $formatted_row = array();
     foreach ( $row as $column => $value ) {
         $formatted_row[] = array($column, $value);
     }
     $all_results[] = $formatted_row;
}
```

Or just use `$column` and `$value` how you like inside the `foreach` loop.

Or do you want specifically the first column, which can be accessed with `reset($row); $first_key = key($row);`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to name a variable with the name of the column?

```
$$row['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];
```

Another way is like this:

```
    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE userName = 'mhopkins321'";
    $result = mysql_query($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    foreach($r as $key=>$value){
        $$key = $value;
    }
```

Now you can echo the values out by their column name.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds redundant, but you could always use array_search:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $value = $row['firstName'];
    $key = array_search($value, $row);
}
```

See more on [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: I receive this error `Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in /home/queryTest.php on line 8`

Comment: Edited my answer.  The result is not the array we should be searching; rather the `$row` is what we need.